# Hexagon effect in javascript slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, effect

My client has been asking about a javascript slider with **hexagon** effect. Something like http://huracan.lamborghini.com/#!/en/gallery (click on a car, then next/previous).

I have been searching the web for a few hours now, but i can't seem to find anything!

Anybody seen this before?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The effects on this page are made drawing in a `canvas` object, not with html/css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, quick google on transitions,javascript and css3 got me to this:

http://www.joelambert.co.uk/flux/

There is an effect named "Blocks2". You might look into the source code of that and adjust it as needed.

Let me know what you think.